# App fails to launch and results in a black screen on device with home button unresponsive

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Im having problems with Xcode timing out to installing the app on my device. The problems persists even if using different devices. Usually 4/5 tries will result in a black screen.

Xcode says successful and the app opens up on the device, but the screen is completely black and the device stops responding.. only a hard reset works.. the home button isn't responsive.
You can however hear that someone is calling you, but you cannot answer the call.

I have no idea of whats wrong, because it builds completely fine.. Any idea on what might be wrong here?

The error Im receiving is:

`error: failed to launch '-- timed out waiting for app to launch`

**Update:**

Someome mentioned to me that it might be a faulty cable, but I get the same black screen when downloading the uploaded app from hockey app.

Answer (score 0):

Often this is the result of building the app in debug with an ad-hoc or release configuration. There was also a bug early in Xcode 5 where it would hang as well, I think this is fixed in the most recent update.